# GPU issues when using Tensorflow2 to train a chatbot

Tags: python, gpu, tensorflow2.0

I’m having trouble using the GPU to run Tensorflow2. I’m trying to train a chatbot, but the GPU doesn’t show up for me to use. I’ve tried everything and can’t get it to work. Here are the details I can provide:

- CUDA Toolkit == 10.1
- cuDNN == 8.0.5
- Tensorflow == 2.12.0
- Keras == 2.12.0
- Python == 3.10 and 3.8 and 3.9

My settings:

- Processor I9-10900k
- GPU: GTX 1050 TI 4GB
- Windows 11

Can anyone help me solve this problem? Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

Script I used to check:

```
import tensorflow as tf

print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))

if tf.test.is_built_with_cuda():
    print("TensorFlow was built with CUDA support.")
else:
    print("TensorFlow was not built with CUDA support.")

print("TensorFlow version: ", tf.__version__)
print(tf.config.experimental.get_device_policy())
```

terminal exit:

```
Num GPUs Available:  0
TensorFlow was not built with CUDA support.
TensorFlow version:  2.10.0
silent
```

Comment: What's the output if you run ```echo CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES```  and if you run ```nvidia-smi``` on your terminal?

Comment: “ TensorFlow was not built with CUDA support.” — you have installed a non-GPU enabled version of Tensorflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the installation page in the [TensorFlow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu). "GPU Support on native-Windows is only available for 2.10 or earlier Versions".

When using TensorFlow 2.10 the following Versions are listed:

| Version | Python version | Compiler | Build tools | cuDNN | CUDA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tensorflow_gpu-2.10.0 | 3.7-3.10 | MSVC 2019 | Bazel 5.1.1 | 8.1 | 11.2 |

Make sure you have the correct versions installed.